# How to describe this kind of education in a non-western society?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

The education I received in primary school and junior high school was comparatively open-minded and libertarian.

I am describing China's education.The word "libertarian" is related with a particular doctrine and institution and lifestyle, all of them are typically western. So if I want to describe an education that is more student-focused, can I use "libertarian", is it too much out of place? "Free" is ambiguous, since it might mean "fee is exempted" here.

Comment: Did it emphasise personal freedom? If so *libertarian* would apply (it can have more specific meanings in some contexts, but that wouldn't be very likely to be a misinterpretation here, especially in lower case). If not, then could you describe it more, as otherwise it's not really possible to help.

Comment: From the Wikipedia page for [Education in China:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_China) *However the education system of the People's Republic of China still discourages innovation and independent thinking*. Also, in the context of wealthy Chinese looking to the US, *Some of the prestige of an American higher education is the result of weaknesses in the PRC's education system, which stifles creativity in favor of rote memorization.* I think the meaning of "libertarian/liberal" here is Primarily Opinion-based.

Comment: Have you looked up a dictionary for the meaning of "libertarian?" Do you think it suits the context? Let us know.

Comment: BTW, why the down vote?

Comment: Libertarian is a highly politicized term here in the US. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarianism_and_Objectivism I doubt that it's the same doctrine and institution you're refering to in China.

Comment: I agree with Wayfaring. "libertarian" will be misconstrued as political, or at the very least confuse the reader. You might as well use the word "liberal," which will convey the same meaning you're trying to express and will less likely be seen as political.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger would people construe "libertarian education" as the narrower sense of "Libertarian"?

Comment: @JonHanna - Doubtful. There are both large-L and small-l libertarians, and any use of the term is likely to conjure visions of Ayn Rand, at least among Americans.

Comment: Libertarian has very specific political meanings and very little use in education. 'free' or 'open' are closer to what you are describing, but probably better to explain than use a single word.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Hanna's comment says, *libertarian* is a fine word to use here, as it seems to mean exactly what you're describing -- the children have [comparatively more] free will when it comes to their educational choices. (If that's not what you meant, then *libertarian* might not be the way to go...)

> So if I want to describe an education that is more student-focused...

If you feel like *libertarian* is incorrect or may be misconstrued, you can always just say that, "[it] was comparatively more open-minded and *student-focused*."

Alternatively, other words that might apply include things like *laissez-faire*, *student-driven*, *permissive*, etc.

Comment: I don't know if it's kosher to comment on your own post like this, but I assume it isn't acceptable to pose another question inside an answer... I've always heard laissez-faire used as an adjective, but the dictionaries I looked at have it listed exclusively as a noun -- is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Although I find myself wishing for a more exact description of the education that you received, I believe that an education which is "libertarian" - maximizing autonomy and freedom of choice - and "student-focused" can be described as one founded on **student-centred learning** or **learner-centred** teaching and learning.

Consider the following [definition](http://www4.ncsu.edu/unity/lockers/users/f/felder/public/Student-Centered.html) (from North Carolina State University; bolding and italics mine):

> In the traditional approach to college teaching, most class time is spent with the professor lecturing and the students watching and listening. The students work individually on assignments, and cooperation is discouraged.
>
> **Student-centered teaching** methods shift the focus of activity from the teacher to the learners. These methods include *active learning*, in which students solve problems, answer questions, formulate questions of their own, discuss, explain, debate, or brainstorm during class; *cooperative learning*, in which students work in teams on problems and projects under conditions that assure both positive interdependence and individual accountability; and *inductive teaching and learning*, in which students are first presented with challenges (questions or problems) and learn the course material in the context of addressing the challenges. Inductive methods include inquiry-based learning, case-based instruction, problem-based learning, project-based learning, discovery learning, and just-in-time teaching. Student-centered methods have repeatedly been shown to be superior to the traditional teacher-centered approach to instruction, a conclusion that applies whether the assessed outcome is short-term mastery, long-term retention, or depth of understanding of course material, acquisition of critical thinking or creative problem-solving skills, formation of positive attitudes toward the subject being taught, or level of confidence in knowledge or skills.

You may also be interested in the article "[Five Characteristics of Learner-Centred Teaching](http://www.facultyfocus.com/articles/effective-teaching-strategies/five-characteristics-of-learner-centered-teaching/)," which describes the principles thus:

> 1. Learner-centered teaching engages students in the hard, messy work of learning.
> 2. Learner-centered teaching includes explicit skill instruction.
> 3. Learner-centered teaching encourages students to reflect on what they are learning and how they are learning it.
> 4. Learner-centered teaching motivates students by giving them some control over learning processes.
> 5. Learner-centered teaching encourages collaboration.

I believe this applies to the type of education you have described with the words "libertarian" and "student-focused."

Side note: While the descriptors you've used point to student-centred learning, and I thus feel I've provided the language you seek, there is a broader educational debate that may or may not ensue here that, while interesting, is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The clearest way to describe, for a Western audience, the style of education that you received in China might be to start by indicating what it was not—namely, a traditional, passive, rote-style, information-cramming method that gives students very little opportunity for independent research and creative thought. Then you can outline the ways in which your education differed from that image of a traditional Chinese education.

I advise against trying to compress your description of the style of education you received into a single word or phrase unless you are confident that it matches what Western educators mean when they use the word or phrase in question—and my impression is that Western educators agree about almost nothing. There is certainly no advantage to using a Western pedagogical label to describe a non-Western educational style that only very roughly approximates what that label refers to in a Western context.

If you learned in a system that in some ways was closer to a Western style of education than to a traditional Chinese style, you can describe it in a shorthand way as "a more Western style of education"—but really that doesn't say much. It's just a starting point from which begin detailing how your education differed from a traditional one.